# Passing a parameter though an event handler

Tags: c#, list, handler, designer

I want to pass List < int > ScoresList through -----------------------------------V

```
    private void lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int target = lstStudents.SelectedIndex;
        if (target != -1)
        {
            Student student = (Student)students[target];
            txtScoreCount.Text = Convert.ToString(ScoresList.Count);
        }
    }
```

To access------------------------------------------------------------------------------^ the # of scores in my list.

When I do, I have access to my ScoresList, however, I get a "

> No overload for 'lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'.

The error is more specifically located here in my Designer.

```
this.lstStudents.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

I do not know what to put here that will resolve the issue. Since I'm here I assume I shouldn't pass a parameter through my event? How do I resolve this?

Comment: I've also tried:
txtScoreCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Student.ScoresList.Count)
Now I get an object reference is required for the non-static field.... doesn't help me though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding parameter to event handler doesn't makes sense. Think of who responsible of passing the parameter value? The event handler **get invoked by system** upon occurrence of respective event. Also event handler method required to follow specific predefined signature, and adding parameter changes method signature, hence you got that error message.

Possible solution is to declare `ScoresList` as global variable so it will be accessible accross methods in the same scope, including your event handler method.

```
private List<int> ScoresList = new List<int>();

private void lstStudents_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int target = lstStudents.SelectedIndex;
    if (target != -1)
    {
        Student student = (Student)students[target];
        txtScoreCount.Text = Convert.ToString(ScoresList.Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sooooo, close. My issue is getting the correct List<int> ScoresList from another list List<Students> ScoresList. In my Class Students, I can access each individual list, however, making the List<int> ScoresList in my Form1 code is proving more difficult. I want the selected Student's Scores to be counted and displayed.

Comment: Figured it out! Used the global declaration to create a blank List<int> ScoresList. Then was able to use my target variable to choose which student from my students collection (code not included). 

txtScoreCount.Text = Convert.ToString(students[target].ScoresList.Count);